# Program doesnt output anything

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am currently buffer overflow with C. I am just a beginner so please be easy on me.

```
int main( ) {
 char *name[2];
 name[0] = "/bin/sh";
 name[1] = NULL;
 execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

This is the output I got:[image] It seems when I compile and execute it, it switches to "/bin/sh", is this output normal or am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <unistd.h> 

 int main(void) {
 char buf[7 + 1 + 4 + 4] = "/bin/sh<garbage>";

 *(buf + 7) = 0;
 *((char**)(buf + 8)) = buf;
 *((char**)(buf + 12)) = NULL;
 syscall(11, buf + 0, buf + 8, buf + 12);
}
```

for this code, I am asked to briefly explain the simplifications and run it to explain the output. However as shown in the screenshot, it doesnt output anything at all, how should I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it switches to "/bin/sh", is this output normal or am I doing something wrong?

Yes in both cases you execute *sh* so the prompt change, and you can enter commands like if you started *sh* in a console. To finish *sh* execution enter *exit* or a control-d

> it doesnt output anything at all

That means you do not enter in *sh*

That second program supposes the pointers are on 32b because of the lines

```
*((char**)(buf + 8)) = buf;
 *((char**)(buf + 12)) = NULL;
```

if you are in 64b it will not work as expected, force to compile in 32b.

If you are in 32b modify its definition to for instance print the value return by *syscall*

---

of course it is possible to modify the program to work on 64b :

```
int main(void) {
 char buf[7 + 1 + 8 + 8] = "/bin/sh<garbage........>";

 *(buf + 7) = 0;
 *((char**)(buf + 8)) = buf;
 *((char**)(buf + 16)) = NULL;
 syscall(59, buf + 0, buf + 8, buf + 16);
}
```

As indicated in a remark 11 if for x86 (and ARMv7 with is my case on a PI4) and 59 for x86-64

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea on the second programme where it doesnt have any output?

Comment: "First modify its definition to know the value return by syscall" I am not sure how to do that

Comment: @stevielol are you in 32B or 64b ?

Comment: I am running kali(64b) on a vm

Comment: @stevielol this is why it does not work, compile in 32b, *gcc -m32 ...* if using *gcc*

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I don't think the point is to print the return value. I think the program is supposed to execute `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne of course it is supposed to execute *sh*, this is what I say in my answer. But this is not the case for the OP and I also indicate the reason : the OP is in 64b but the program suppose 32B

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. If I remember correctly the execve syscall number for x86-64 is 59, but I'll have to consult the documentation to be sure.

Comment: It's also that they use 11 instead of 59.

Comment: @S.S.Anne that I didn't know, can you explain ?

Comment: The syscall number for execve on x86 is 11, while on x86-64 it's 59.

Comment: @S.S.Anne ah ok, thank you

Comment: I got an error :(  , I posted on the questions

Comment: @stevielol compile in 64b with the definition I give at the end of my (edited) answer

Comment: @stevielol I just moved on a x86-64 and the definition for 64b works

Comment: @bruno I just modified the script like u asked, did u get the same output as I did from the screenshot I just post

Comment: @bruno Yea, I will edit it out later.  Just to make sure the 2c programme executes to sh like the first program, is that the correct output? Thanks for your patient

Comment: @stevielol yes it is the expected behavior. "Thanks for your patient " : I agree because it is 0 AM 30 :-) (you are in UK I am in France)

Comment: I am really sorry

Comment: @stevielol no problem it was a joke, sleep time for me now, happy coding